# How can I show that $(x-1)(x^2-1)$ divides the polynomial $(x^n-1)(x^{n+1}-1)$?

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, divisibility

How can I show that $(x-1)(x^2-1)$ divides the polynomial $(x^n-1)(x^{n+1}-1)$?

Comment: Welcome to the site. To typeset math include it between dollar-symbols. Like  `$x^2 - 1$` Use two dollar symbols for displayed mode.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stack.exchange. You will get better answers if you indicate what you have tried to solve this problem. In this case, a good way to start is to try to do a few simple cases by hand, e.g. $n = 2, n = 3, n = 4$. Use the formula $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ and more generally $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \dots + x + 1)$.

Comment: You immediately have the rearrangement $(x-1)^2(x+1)$, and it should be directly obvious that $(x-1)^2$ divides the given polynomial.  What is left is to show that $x+1$ also divides this polynomial, which can be done fairly quickly by comparing the polynomials $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i$ modulo $x+1$.

Answer (score 3):

- Show/recall that $x-1$ divides $x^k - 1$.
- Use that to show  $x^2 - 1 $ divides $(x^2)^k -1$, that is $x^2 - 1$ divides $x^m -1$ for even $m$.
- Distinguish cases according to $n$ odd and even.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of $f(x):=(x-1)(x^2-1)$ are the multiset $\{1,1,-1\}$. One of $n$ or $n+1$ is even. Assume without loss of generality $n$ is even so that $1$ and $-1$ are roots of $x^n-1$. The other root $1$ is then a root of $x^{n+1}-1$.

So all the roots of $f(x)$ are roots of $g(x):=(x^n-1)(x^{n+1}-1)$ and so by the Factor Theorem all the factors of $f(x)$ are factors of $g(x)$; i.e. $f(x)$ divides $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x-1|x^n-1$$ Now, if $n$ is odd $x+1|x^{n+1}-1$, if $n$ is even then $x-1|x^n-1$. Thus the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

only trouble is showing that $(x+1)$ divides $f(x) = (x^n - 1)(x^{n+1} -1).$  but $$f(-1) = ((-1)^{n} - 1)((-1)^{n+1} - 1)$$ one of $n$ or $n+1$ must be even therefore $f(-1) = 0$ and $f$ is divisible by $(x+1).$